# When A moves from one side of the dot product to the other, it becomes $A^T$

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm going through the book Gilbert Strang - Introduction to Linear Algebra, Third Edition (2003) and in the section for transpose matrices right near the end, there is this paragraph: [image: paragraph]
I completely understand the transformation, but I don't understand what the 'deep purpose' here really is.

Also, I don't understand in the last sentence how "$A$ moves from one side of the dot product to the other".

What i see in $(Ax)^Ty$ is: $A$ firstly linearly transforms the vector **x** and then the resulting vector is turned into a linear transformation on its own (thanks to the transpose operation). Now, **y** is linearly transformed with this new transformation and the end result is a single number.

My point is, there was never explicit dotting between **x** and **y** in the first place, so what does the author mean $A$ going from one side to the other?

Comment: Where do you see “$(A^Tx)y$” in that text?

Comment: I meant $(Ax)^Ty$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By dotting, the author probably means that $\vec{a} .\vec{b} = a^Tb$, for *vectors* $a$  and $b$, so

$(Ax)^Ty = (Ax).y$,

and $x^T(A^T y ) = x.(A^Ty)$, note that $Ax$ and $A^Ty$ are vectors.

Comment: So, he talks about the duality that every vector x is associated with a linear transformation that takes space from len(x)-dimensional space to the number line?

Comment: @zafirzarya yes, you can say that if you see $Ax$ or $A^T y$ as a linear transformation

Comment: @zafirzarya Elements of the dual space are functionals that take a vector and return a scalar. If you choose the correct pair of bases for both spaces, vectors can be represented as column coordinate vectors of and dual vectors as row coordinate vectors, with evaluation of the functional becoming simple matrix (effectively dot product) multiplication.